# Firstname, middlename and lastname MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to make a combined search on the first, middle and lastname. The query is:

```
SELECT  picture,person_id,   firstname+ ' ' +middlename+ ' ' +lastname AS fullName
FROM    PERSON
WHERE   (firstname+ ' ' +middlename+ ' ' +lastname LIKE"%#queryString#%")
```

Now this is working for: Peter den Test (first/ middle/ last)
This is not working for: Marc Baker (first / no middle name /last). I have to type in two spaces before Marc  Baker shows up. Can I check if the middle name is empty in the query?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `ISNULL(middlename, '') ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
SELECT  picture,person_id,   firstname+ ' ' +middlename+ ' ' +lastname AS fullName
FROM    PERSON
WHERE   (firstname+ ' ' + LTRIM(middlename + ' ') + lastname LIKE"%#queryString#%")
```

Comment: This would work when there is no middlename, but would eliminate space between middlename and lastname when middlename exists.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic It wouldn't as it is an `LTRIM` and not `TRIM`.

Comment: @jyparask - it's `RTRIM` that's going to eliminate the space. It's ok now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
WHERE   (firstname+ ' ' +LTRIM(middlename+ ' ' +lastname) LIKE"%#queryString#%")
```

Comment: I like this idea. Just replace `TRIM` with `LTRIM`. `TRIM` function does not exist in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `CASE` to do the check, something like:

```
SELECT  picture,person_id,   firstname+ ' ' +middlename+ ' ' +lastname AS fullName
FROM    PERSON
WHERE   (firstname
          + CASE WHEN middlename = '' OR middlename IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' +middlename END 
          + ' ' +lastname LIKE"%#queryString#%")
```